# Docker daemon answers '404 page not found' after update

Tags: docker, http-proxy

I recently updated my docker from 1.4 to 1.5 (with the package `lxc_docker`).

Since then, docker daemon sends an error like this (for every command):

```
$ docker version 
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
```

But if I use the previous version of the client, i get the fine answer:

```
$ /usr/bin/docker-old version 
Client version: 1.4.0
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 4595d4f
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

It seems to be proxy settings (`HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` variables are used on this server), and I can *solve* the problem by setting the `NO_PROXY` variable:

```
$ export NO_PROXY="/var/run/docker.sock"
$ docker version  
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

Do you know where this problem **really** come from? And how to **cleanly** solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a new 1.5 feature, a guy from docker  (@icecrime on twitter) has confirmed it.
the documentation is up to date : https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10192/files

So you don't have to cleanly solve it. This is the right way to use docker behind a proxy.

Comment: It's not a feature, it's a bug and it was fixed in version 1.6.0  – see my answer.

Comment: Obviously this kind of "feature" has not been appreciated  by users and has been fixed to the right way in 1.6.0 (https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10739) which goes out yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

> Do you know where this problem really come from?

The problem comes from the fact that docker needlessly (one could argue erroneously) tries to use proxy (if specified by `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables) to access **local** unix domain socket at `/var/run/docker.sock`.

> And how to cleanly solve it?

This was [fixed](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10739) in version 1.6.0 by not trying to use proxy in this case. As a result there's no need to add `/var/run/docker.sock` to `NO_PROXY` environment variable any more.